# How would I change this to Loop and Array Notation?

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, loops

I have 4 text boxes in form1 named txtParent. It's the last if statement that I'm asking about. Each text box must be filled in by the user before the form is allowed to submit. How could I change that into a Loop and Array but still work how it's supposed to?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Field Trip Consent Form</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function validates() { 
var radioChecked = false;
var moMonth = document.getElementById("getMonth").value;
var moDay = document.getElementById("getDay").value;

for(var i=0; i< document.form1.permission.length; i++) {

if(document.form1.permission[i].checked) {
      radioChecked = true;          
    }
}
if(radioChecked == false) {      
    alert("Please chose permission Status");
    return false;          
} 
if(document.form1.destination.value == "") {
    alert("Please type in the Destination textbox");   
    return false;     
}   

if(moMonth == 'Month') { 
    alert("Please select a Month"); 
    return false; 
}   
if(moDay == 'Day') { 
    alert("Please select a Day"); 
    return false;
}   
if(document.form1.txtParent.value == "") {
    alert("Please type in the txtParent textbox");    
    return false;            
}
return true;        
}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<h1>Field Trip Consent Form</h1>

<form name="form1" onsubmit="return validates()" method='post' 
 action="http://legacy.jefferson.kctcs.edu/users/mark.prather/formhandler.asp"> 

<form>

<h2>Description of Trip</h2>
<p>Destination &nbsp;

<input type="text" name="destination" SIZE="50" /></p>
<p>Date of Trip &nbsp;
<select name="month" id='getMonth'>
<option selected value="Month">Month</option>
<option value="Jan">Jan</option>
<option value="Feb">Feb</option>
<option value="Mar">Mar</option>
<option value="Apr">Apr</option>
<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="Jun">Jun</option>
<option value="Jul">Jul</option>
<option value="Aug">Aug</option>
<option value="Sep">Sep</option>
<option value="Oct">Oct</option>
<option value="Nov">Nov</option>
<option value="Dec">Dec</option>
</select>
<select name="day" id='getDay'>
<option selected value="Day">Day
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>

<select name="year">
<option selected value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>

<h2>Parental Information</h2>
<p>Mother's Name &nbsp;
<input type="text" name="txtParent" size="20" /></p>
<p>Mother's Work Phone &nbsp;
<input type="text" name="txtParent" size="20" /></p>
<p>Father's Name &nbsp;
<input type="text" name="txtParent" size="20" /></p>
<p>Father's Work Phone &nbsp;
<input type="text" name="txtParent" size="20" /></p>

<p><input type="radio" name="permission" value="yes" /> Permission is Granted &nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="permission" value="no" /> Permission is NOT Granted &nbsp;</p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Submit This Data" /> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
<input type="reset" /></p> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your `form` tag and/or `submit` button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to loop through and validate all txtParent elemnts, then

`document.getElementsByTagName` will return you all DOM elements matching that name.

```
   var inputs = document.getElementsByName("txtParent");
    for(var i  =0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
        if(inputs[i].value === "") {
             alert("Your error message here");
             return false;
        }
    }
```

Else if you want to use `[]` notation in `txtParent`, then

Your HTML will become:

```
<h2>Parental Information</h2>
<p>Mother's Name &nbsp;
<input type="text" name="txtParent[]" size="20" /></p>
<p>Mother's Work Phone &nbsp;
<input type="text" name="txtParent[]" size="20" /></p>
<p>Father's Name &nbsp;
<input type="text" name="txtParent[]" size="20" /></p>
<p>Father's Work Phone &nbsp;
<input type="text" name="txtParent[]" size="20" /></p>
```

And in JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[name='txtParent[]']")
```

This will return you a NodeList. So you need to iterate and check if the field is empty or not.

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[name='txtParent[]']");
for(var i  =0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].value === "") {
         alert("Your error message here");
         return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to say your first answer actually answered my question so thank you mohamedrias!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, try this.

```
setInterval(function(){
    if (document.form1.txtParent.value != "") {
      alert('TextBox is full')
       return true;
    }
   },1)
```

I suppose you could execute a script when the text is changed too.

You could also use jQuery:

```
$( "txtParent" ).change(function() {
  alert( "Changed!" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest first changing your HTML slightly, in order to give a unique name to each of the `<input>` elements; otherwise it's likely, in the server-side, that the last value submitted will overwrite all the others (though if you want an array, you could simply append `[]` to the name):

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  <h2>Parental Information</h2>
  <p>Mother's Name &nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="mothersName" size="20" />
  </p>
  <p>Mother's Work Phone &nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="mothersPhone" size="20" />
  </p>
  <p>Father's Name &nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="fathersName" size="20" />
  </p>
  <p>Father's Work Phone &nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="fathersPhone" size="20" />
  </p>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

I'm assuming that, in your actual project, you've wrapped the form elements in a `<form>` element, and supplied some means of submitting that form; but I've added those here for the purposes of the demonstration.

As for the JavaScript, I'd suggest:

```
// a named function to perform the checks:
function validate(event) {
  // 'event' and 'this' are passed in automagically from
  // the addEventListener() used later.

  // here we prevent the default action (form submission):
  event.preventDefault();

  // caching the 'this' in case we need to use it again:
  var self = this,
    // retrieving the <input> elements of the <form> (the 'this')
    // using document.querySelectorAll(), and a CSS selector:
    textInputs = this.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]'),

    // converting the NodeList to an Array, using
    // Array.prototype.slice() and Function.prototype.call():
    textInputArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(textInputs, 0),

    // filtering that array to find the <input> elements
    // whose value (after removing leading/trailing white-space)
    // is equal to an empty string:
    empties = textInputArray.filter(function(input) {
      // removing the 'invalid' class-name from all <input> elements:
      input.classList.remove('invalid');

      // keeping only those elements for which the assessment
      // returns true:
      return input.value.trim() === '';
    });

  // iterating over the empties (the array of empty-value
  // <input> elements):
  empties.forEach(function(input) {
    // adding the 'invalid' class:
    input.classList.add('invalid');

    // leaving a message (to the console, not an alert()),
    // using the nodeValue (text) of the <input>'s previous sibling,
    // after removing leading/trailing white-space and converting
    // it to lower-case:
    console.log("Please enter " + input.previousSibling.nodeValue.trim().toLowerCase());
  });
}

// getting the first (or no) <form> element from the document,
// and assigning the named function as the event-handler for the
// submit event:
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', validate);
```

```js
function validate(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var self = this,
    textInputs = this.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]'),
    textInputArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(textInputs, 0),
    empties = textInputArray.filter(function(input) {
      input.classList.remove('invalid');
      return input.value.trim() === '';
    });

  empties.forEach(function(input) {
    input.classList.add('invalid');
    console.log("Please enter " + input.previousSibling.nodeValue.trim().toLowerCase());
  });
}

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', validate);
```

```css
.invalid {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <h2>Parental Information</h2>
  <p>Mother's Name &nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="mothersName" size="20" />
  </p>
  <p>Mother's Work Phone &nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="mothersPhone" size="20" />
  </p>
  <p>Father's Name &nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="fathersName" size="20" />
  </p>
  <p>Father's Work Phone &nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="fathersPhone" size="20" />
  </p>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

I'd also further change your HTML to properly associate the label-text to the relevant `<input>` element, and associate groups of `<input>` elements together to represent their relationship to each other:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  <h2>Parental Information</h2>
  <!-- using the fieldset element to group associated form fields
       together -->
  <fieldset>
    <!-- the legend element provides a title for that 'group'
         of elements -->
    <legend>Mother</legend>
    <label>Mother's Name &nbsp;
      <input type="text" name="mothersName" size="20" />
    </label>
    <label>Mother's Work Phone &nbsp;
      <input type="text" name="mothersPhone" size="20" />
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Father</legend>
    <label>Father's Name
      <input type="text" name="fathersName" size="20" />
    </label>
    <label>Father's Work Phone &nbsp;
      <input type="text" name="fathersPhone" size="20" />
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

```js
function validate(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var self = this,
    textInputs = this.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]'),
    textInputArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(textInputs, 0),
    empties = textInputArray.filter(function(input) {
      input.classList.remove('invalid');
      return input.value.trim() === '';
    });

  empties.forEach(function(input) {
    input.classList.add('invalid');
    console.log("Please enter " + input.previousSibling.nodeValue.trim().toLowerCase());
  });
}

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', validate);
```

```css
.invalid {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

label {
  display: block;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <h2>Parental Information</h2>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Mother</legend>
    <label>Mother's Name &nbsp;
      <input type="text" name="mothersName" size="20" />
    </label>
    <label>Mother's Work Phone &nbsp;
      <input type="text" name="mothersPhone" size="20" />
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Father</legend>
    <label>Father's Name
      <input type="text" name="fathersName" size="20" />
    </label>
    <label>Father's Work Phone &nbsp;
      <input type="text" name="fathersPhone" size="20" />
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

References:

- HTML:

  - [`<fieldset>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset).
  - [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).
  - [`<legend>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: Thank you for all the information! I'll look through it and it might just help me at a later time.